# При использовании библиотеки CV2 предупреждения Cannot move to target thread

Tags: python, opencv

При использовании в своей программе на python 3.X вызовов функций из библиотеки CV возникают предупреждения:

> QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x5642cf87c870) is not the
> object's thread (0x5642cf53efe0). Cannot move to target thread
> (0x5642cf87c870)
>
> QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x5642cf87c870) is not the
> object's thread (0x5642cf53efe0). Cannot move to target thread
> (0x5642cf87c870)

На конечный результат выполнения программы не влияют, cv функции отрабатывают, отрисовывают изображения, но "замусоривают" экран. Искал как это устранить, много советов, кому то помогает наверное, мне найденные советы не помогли. Ищу новые идеи как эту проблему решить.
Наверняка кто работал с CV с этим уже сталкивался.

Фрагмент кода

```
import cv2

pf = 'tt.png'

img = cv2.imread(pf, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

rows,cols = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]

cv2.imshow("Example", img)

cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: У вас здесь не cv2 проблемы а с PyQt5)

Comment: Хорошо. Что делать? Я устанавливал PyQt5 с conda  и pip. Удалял, снова устанавливал. Предупреждения все равно остаются.

Comment: Покажите минимально воспроизводимый пример кода, который приводит к этой ошибке.

Comment: import cv2

pf = 'tt.png'

img = cv2.imread(pf, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
rows,cols = img.shape[0], img.shape[1]

cv2.imshow("Example", img)
cv2.waitKey()

Comment: Я не уверен но разве cv2 по катом использует Qt?

Comment: Я деинсталлировал PyQt5 но ошибка остается. В небольшом фрагменте кода используется только CV. Какие идеи?

Comment: Попробуйте понизить версию cv2.